# Nuxt typescript building and transpile project for deployment

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a Vue application built with the NuxtJS framework using the `yarn create nuxt-app` utility.

The application is meant to be for **Server-Side-Rendering** meaning it has to run on an actual server instance.

I am using `Nuxt-ts` to be able to use typescript with Nuxt, my `nuxt.config.js` looks like this:

```
export default {
  ssr: true,
  srcDir: 'src/',
  buildModules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/typescript
    '@nuxt/typescript-build',
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/stylelint
    '@nuxtjs/stylelint-module',
  ],

  server: {
    port: envsConfig.env.ENV_CP_HTTP_PORT || 2055,
  }
}
```

When building using `nuxt-ts build`, I get a folder `.nuxt` with the results of the build phase,

My scripts are:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt-ts",
    "build": "nuxt-ts build",
    "start": "nuxt-ts start"
}
```

The question now, how can I deploy this on a server and run it using node?

Cuz running `node .nuxt/dist/server/server.js` doesn't seem to work, and I got confused.

Also, `nuxt-ts` seems to transpile in `runtime`, where I want my application to be built+transpiled then copy the results and run them using node,

Any help would be awesome!
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `nuxt-ts` isn't mandatory. It's only useful for `.ts` files not compiled by webpack (typically the `nuxt.config.ts`). If you have `nuxt.config.js` in vanilla javascript, you can stay with the standard `nuxt` binary (no the `nuxt-ts`).
But you can keep it if you want. I'm just saying it's not mandatory for nuxt in Typescript.

---

That say, run `nuxt build`, and it will bundle everything you need for production inside `.nuxt` folder.

All you have to do then is publish this folder, and run `nuxt start` to run the production server :)

Comment: since my project has typescript (.ts files) when running `nuxt start or nuxt build`  I get complication errors: `Invalid or unexpected token: const activeTheme = .....`

Comment: Also, how come running `nuxt start` inside `.nuxt/` folder will work? since there is no `package.json` nor `node_modules` inside `.nuxt` which means `nuxt start` or `yarn start` won't be a known command

Comment: The important package for typescript is [@nuxt/typescript-build](https://typescript.nuxtjs.org/guide/setup/).
What I personally do is create a Docker image with my code -> `nuxt build` -> `nuxt start` and that's it. Of course you need the package.json and node_modules to run it on a deployed environment. But each time it depends on how you deploy it

Comment: figured it out, had to update the version of typescript-build, and replace `nuxt-ts` with `nuxt` and it worked! thank you